# Telerik - How to insert image into RadEditor without ImageManager (or RadUpload)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm working with ASP.NET Web Forms and Telerik.

I want to insert an image to a `RadEditor`.

How do I do it without the `ImageManager` component? I want just a simple file dialog. (like when you '*Right click > Save as...*' in Chrome).

**What i've searched around so far:**

- I've been capable of making a custom dialog, but instead of the file dialog being brought up, a very ugly window with a 'Select' button appears instead (a `RadUpload`). I want the file dialog *only!*

```html
<telerik:RadEditor ID="radEditorContratoConfissao" runat="server" >
    <Tools>
        <telerik:EditorToolGroup Tag="Main">
            <telerik:EditorTool Name="Custom" />
        </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
    </Tools>
    <ImageManager ViewPaths="" UploadPaths="" DeletePaths=""></ImageManager>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.CommandList["Custom"] = function(commandName, editor, args) {

        var myCallbackFunction = function(sender, args) {
           editor.pasteHtml(String.format("<img src={0} /> ", args.href))
        }

        editor.showExternalDialog('UploadDialogForm.aspx',
        {},
        270,
        300,
        myCallbackFunction,
        null,
        'Insert Image',
        true,
        Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close + Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Move,
        false,
        false);
    };
</script>
```

I've also tried to create an `input` element, right in the javascript function, to no avail. Thanks in advance for any comments or efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: You can try the light InsertImage dialog (it is a built-in dialog where the user provides a URL to an image hosted somewhere in the Net).

Solution 2: To register the [external dialog files](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/customdialogs/defaultcs.aspx) and to customize the FileBrowser.ascx file which is part of radeditor Image Manager dialog. Remove the fluff and keep only the feature you'd like to present to your customers/

Solution 3: You can download an example based on a custom dialog from https://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/162892_customdialogs.zip?sfvrsn=e4c992bb_0

Comment: Thanks for the input, but i've tried this one out already. In fact, it's in the "What i've searched so far" segment of the question. The issue with this approach is that instead of a file dialog, some ugly window appears with a "Select" button (which is a `RadUpload` component). I'd want a file dialog, without the fluff.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information. I've updated my reply based on it.